# função de busca em uma lista angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algoritmo-de-busca

Oi, estou tenho uma função que pesquisa em uma lista a ocorrência de alguma string digitada no campo que é passado como seu parâmetro, ela funciona bem para buscar essas strings:

```js
$scope.$watch('q', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (oldValue != null){
           $http.get('/api/services.json?q=' + newValue)
       .success(function (data) {
         $scope.services = data;});
  }
 }, true);
}]);
```

O problema que é apresentado é que quando apago qualquer caractere da busca que fiz a função retorna todos os elementos do conjunto!
Este código é que busca o que foi feito na função.

```html
 <div class="search">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por serviços" ng-model="q">
</div>
<div class="banner">
 
 <div class="search">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por serviços" ng-model="q">
</div> 
 <h2 class="title" style="color: #A2121F;">Serviços em destaque
  </h2> 
 </div>
<h3 ng-if="services.length == 0">Nenhum serviço encontrado.</h3>
<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item", "columnWidth": 200 }'> 
 <div class="col-6 services_card" ng-repeat="service in services" ng-if="service.active == true">
  <a class="section" href="{{ service.url }}">
     <h3 class="title" >{{service.name}}</h3>  
  </a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Nesta linha $http.get('/api/services.json?q=' + newValue) é para retornar as ocorrências, em um arquivo json, da string, isso ele faz, mas quando vou apagando a string que está como parâmetro ele retorna todos os elementos que estão no .json. O fato é que a página está paginada, organizada de 8 em 8 elementos, que são parte do .json, quando apago a string que está como parâmetro ele retorna todos os elementos do json, não mantem a paginação!
Já tentei colocar um refresh quando fosse apagando mas deu errado!
Grato pela atenção!

Comment: Por favor, se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: editei o enunciado

Comment: Voce quer apenas filtrar a sua lista atual ou filtrar a lista total?
Se for um filtro da lista atual, use "| filter: { name: q }" no ng-repeat e remova o $watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta seus dados não estão sendo filtrados corretamente por paginação. Por isso fiz um exemplo em que monitoro a variável `q` para filtrar um `array` e aplicar a paginação. Note que não utilizar um serviço não faz nenhuma diferença nesse caso:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('appExemploPaginacao', []);

  angular
    .module('appExemploPaginacao')
    .controller('PaginacaoController', PaginacaoController);

  PaginacaoController.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

  function PaginacaoController($scope, $filter) {
    var paginacao = this;
    var servicos = [];
    var resultados = [];
    
    iniciar();
    
    function iniciar() {
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 1', ativo: true});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 12', ativo: true});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 123', ativo: false});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 1234', ativo: true});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 12345', ativo: true});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 123456', ativo: true});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 123457', ativo: true});
      servicos.push({nome: 'Serviço 1234578', ativo: true});

      paginacao.q = '';
      paginacao.pagina = 1;
      $scope.$watch('paginacao.q', monitorarQ, true);
      $scope.$watch('paginacao.pagina', monitorarPagina, true);
    }
    
    function monitorarQ() {
      resultados = $filter('filter')(servicos, {nome: paginacao.q, ativo: true});
      monitorarPagina();
    }

    function monitorarPagina() {
      var indice = (paginacao.pagina * 3) - 3;

      paginacao.visiveis = $filter('limitTo')(resultados, 3, indice);
    }
  }
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div ng-app="appExemploPaginacao">
  <div ng-controller="PaginacaoController as paginacao">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por serviços" ng-model="paginacao.q">
      Pagina: <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="paginacao.pagina" min="1" max="10" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2 class="title" style="color: #A2121F;">Serviços em destaque</h2>
      <div ng-repeat="servico in paginacao.visiveis">
        <h3>{{servico.nome}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```